# Strange bug with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have friend who showed me code that gives different results in Release or Debug configuration in VS2012. There's no multithreading, so I became interested why this happens. It boils down to this: one class has member

```
std::unique_ptr<double[]> m_OldRo;
```

In for loop we do:

```
if(m_OldRo[i] < ro_min)
    ro_min = m_OldRo[i];
```

ro_min defined as double with initial value 10000.
In Debug ro_min always ends up being equal 9.999997e-001. In Release ro_min equals -3.818927e+005. Then things become really strange:

1) If you add such code before if statement, result changes to normal:

```
double doubleValue = 0;
for(size_t k = 0; k < m_Triangles; ++k)
{
    doubleValue  = m_OldRo[k];
    std::cout << "doubleValue = " << doubleValue << "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
doubleValue = 1.000000e+000
doubleValue = 1.000000e+000
doubleValue = 9.999997e-001
doubleValue = 1.000000e+000
doubleValue = 1.000000e+000
doubleValue = 1.000000e+000
doubleValue = 9.999999e-001
doubleValue = 1.000000e+000
doubleValue = 1.000030e+000
doubleValue = 1.000030e+000

ro_min = 9.999997e-001
```

2) If you also add this code, result changes back to wrong:

```
double doubleSum = 0;
for(size_t k = 0; k < m_Triangles; ++k)
{
    doubleSum  += m_OldRo[k];
    std::cout << "doubleSum = " << doubleSum << "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
doubleValue = 1.000000e+000
doubleValue = -3.818927e+005
doubleValue = 9.999997e-001
doubleValue = 3.818947e+005
doubleValue = 1.000000e+000
doubleValue = 1.000000e+000
doubleValue = 9.999999e-001
doubleValue = 1.000000e+000
doubleValue = 1.000030e+000
doubleValue = 1.000030e+000

doubleSum = 1.000000e+000
doubleSum = -3.818917e+005
doubleSum = -3.818907e+005
doubleSum = 4.000000e+000
doubleSum = 5.000000e+000
doubleSum = 6.000000e+000
doubleSum = 7.000000e+000
doubleSum = 8.000000e+000
doubleSum = 9.000030e+000
doubleSum = 1.000006e+001

ro_min = -3.818927e+005
```

Print is just for explanation, it's enough just to add or assign value of m_OldRo[k] to something to change programm behaviour in release version. Does anyone have an idea why this is happens?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I also don't see why you would use unique_ptr here; wouldn't std::vector suffice?

Comment: It would indeed help if you showed us as well how that unique pointer is being initialized.

Comment: Yes, I would use vector of course, but that's not my code, i'm just interested why this happens. It initializes by swap with another unique_ptr in loop. I'll try to make simple complete example today and reformulate the question. Just asked in case someone have seen something like this before.